# SQL - Insert only explicit values and not repeated ones

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script with about 250 entries that are being inserted. The script on its own runs fine however, I run into problems in case of duplicate entries. I could try doing something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [TS].[Configs] WHERE [Id] = 15)
INSERT . . .
```

However, I cannot write this repeated statement over and over for the 250 entries. I have tried setting `Identity_Insert` to `ON` but I still get this error:

```
Exception Message: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'Tbl_LangFiles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '[TS].[Configs]'
```

How can I go about only inserting unique entries in this table?

Comment: try using the MERGE  statement for MS Sql Server

Comment: Could you please help me out a bit more? How would that look here?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Read this blog https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/ for Understanding the MS SQLserver  MERGE statement      
refer the link for details https://pastebin.com/1LCrqx2N

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the UPSERT statement?

```
UPSERT INTO employees (id, name, email) 
VALUES (2, ‘Dennis’, ‘dennisp@weyland.corp’);
```

This will attempt to insert a new record on the database, but if it already exists, it will take the parameters and update.

L.